# Notify Admin of an update in Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, wss, wiki, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

Is there a way to get an update by email when a user updates a wiki page or adds items into the document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply create an alert on the relevant list (Wiki Pages list or the Document Library in question).

Using alerts you can subscribe to new, modified or deleted items and have details emailed to you immediately, daily or weekly.

From the **Actions** menu of a list or document library select the **Alert Me** option and then configure the alert accordingly.

If you like, there's a [video showing how to create an alert on a list](http://office.microsoft.com/training/Training.aspx?AssetID=RP102338251033&CTT=6&Origin=RC102338221033#).